# What companies does Dany command in Meereen?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

**Warning:** This question contains spoilers from *A Dance With Dragons*.

[Danaerys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenerys_Targaryen) takes [Meereen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Meereen) and establishes her claim over it, as well as feeling a sense of protectiveness for the people she has freed there.

During her stay and also along her path to get there, many people flock to her cause, most of whom are companies of sellswords or similar armies.

It seems like there are a lot, and I'm having a difficult time remembering who they all are.

**Please provide a break-down of who her companies are**.

**Bonus** - name their leaders and approximate sizes as well.

The ones which I know so far are:

- The **[Stormcrows](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stormcrows)** - lead by [Daario Naharis](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daario_Naharis) --> 500 men
- The **[Unsullied](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Unsullied)** - lead by [Grey Worm](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Grey_Worm) --> 10,000 men
- The **[Second Sons](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Second_Sons)** - lead by [Brown Ben Plumm](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ben_Plumm) --> 500 men
- The **[Brazen Beasts](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brazen_Beasts)** - lead by the [Shavepate](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Skahaz_mo_Kandaq) --> Unknown

aaaaaaaaand my mind goes blank after those!

---

<sup>I know I'm venturing into list territory here, but I am convinced that this list is limited.</sup>

Comment: That's pretty much it I think

Comment: @SystemDown I remember something like, the Freedmen, Stalwart shields?, and some others which I don't fully remember right now. Might do some more digging...

Comment: @Mooz: Mother's Men, Free Brothers, and Stalward Sheilds. See [Ruling Council of Meereen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Ruling_council_of_Meereen#The_council_members)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List of companies under command of Daenerys is covered in the Appendix of "A Dance With Dragons". Check "The Queen across the water".

You can also check it [online](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons-Appendix#THE_QUEEN_ACROSS_THE_WATER)

under the section of her captains and commanders

> her captains and commanders:
>
> - DAARIO NAHARIS, a flamboyant Tyroshi sellsword, captain of the Stormcrows, a free company,
> - BEN PLUMM, called BROWN BEN, a mongrel sellsword, captain of the Second Sons, a free company.
> - GREY WORM, a eunuch, commander of the Unsullied, a company of eunuch infantry,
>
>   - HERO, an Unsullied captain, second-in-command,
>   - STALWART SHIELD, an Unsullied spearman,
> - MOLLONO YOS DOB, commander of the Stalwart Shields, a company of freedmen,
> - SYMON STRIPEBACK, commander of FREE BROTHERS, a company of freedmen,
> - MARSELEN, commander of the MOTHER’S MEN, a company of freedman, a eunuch, brother to Missandei,
> - GROLEO of Pentos, formerly captain of the great cog Saduleon, now an admiral without a fleet,
> - ROMMO, a jaqqa rhan of the Dothraki,

under the section of her protectors:

> her protectors:
>
> - SER BARRISTAN SELMY, called BARRISTAN THE BOLD, Lord Commander of the Queensguard,
>
>   - his lads, squires training for knighthood:
>   - TUMCO LHO, of the Basilisk Isles,
>   - LARRAQ, called THE LASH, of Meereen,
>   - THE RED LAMB, a Lhazarene freedman,
>   - the BOYS, three Ghiscari brothers,
> - STRONG BELWAS, eunuch and former fighting slave,
> - her Dothraki bloodriders:
>
>   - JHOGO, the whip, blood of her blood,
>   - AGGO, the bow, blood of her blood,
>   - RAKHARO, the arakh, blood of her blood,

under the section of her Meereenese court

> her Meereenese court:
>
> - SKAHAZ MO KANDAQ, called THE SHAVEPATE, shaven-headed commander of the Brazen Beasts, her city watch,

Comment: I *always* forget to check the appendices! Good work!

Comment: Excellent find!

Comment: @Mooz, isn't also ship companies ? I remember her using some ships...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Nika G.'s answer, I add the ships Illyrio Mopatis offered Daenerys.

1. **Summer Sun**, renamed **Vhagar**. *200 oars*.
2. **Saduleon**, renamed **Balerion**. Merchant ship, captained by Groleo
3. **Joso's Prank**, renamed **Meraxes**. *200 oars*. Nicknamed Joso's Cock after being used to penetrate the eastern gate of Meereen.

However, during the siege of Meereen, this ships were dismembered to build siege instruments.