# What is the composition and strength of Queen Daenerys's army invading Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As of the end of season 6 of Game of Thrones, [Queen Daenerys is leading the much awaited invasion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCMaaC1tyPg) of Westeros. Her fleet on the screen is impressive, covering the sea to the horizon, not to mention sailing under three enormous dragons.

I'm curious of the number and the composition of the invading army. This is what I know so far:

1. [Unsullied](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Unsullied): She acquired 8000 of them from Kraznys the slaver (S3E04). Luckily, the Unsullied did not have to fight in Yunkai, or Meereen, as they were brought under control without large battles. But, a considerable number of them must have died because of uprising of the [Sons of the Harpy](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sons_of_the_Harpy) and the Battle of Meereen. How many of the 8000 remain now?
2. <strike>[Second Sons](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Second_Sons): When the sellsword company offers their allegiance, they were 2000 strong. Were there any deaths in Meereen because of Sons of the Harpy and the Battle of Meereen? Is the company still intact? (In the books, some of them switch sides and side with the slavers).</strike> The Second Sons stay in Meereen, as comments have pointed out.
3. Dothraki Screamers: After killing all the former Khals at [Khalar Vezhven](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Khalar_Vezhven), she leads a large population of the Dothraki race. How many fighting Dothraki men serve her? Do we have an estimate?
4. [The Iron Fleet](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Iron_Fleet): Yara and Theon brought a large number of ships and men to sail them. Do we have an estimate on the number of men/ships?
5. Slaver's Navy: Did any of the Navy enter Queen's service after the Battle of Meereen? Do we have an estimate on how many ships/men she has?
6. Various companies unspecified in the show (?): In the books we have [Brazen Beasts](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brazen_Beasts), [Mother's Men](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mother%27s_Men), [Free Brothers](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Free_Brothers), [Stalwart Shields](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stalwart_Shields), and [Stormcrows](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stormcrows). None of these entities are mentioned in TV show, as far as I remember. Or am I wrong?
7. Martells and Tyrells: Many viewers [spotted](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/4q19ay/main_spoilers_varyss_movement_explained_proof/) the [Martell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2BTP.png) and [Tyrell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNTjl.png) sails in Queen's fleet. But we can safely assume that they were only delegates. The Southern houses would be fools to transport an army to Meereen and back for no reason.

Putting aside possible Westerosi armies who would join her later, who else is in Queen Daenerys's conquering army and what are their numbers?

Comment: FYI, the Storm Crows have been replaced by the Second Sons in the show. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129268/why-were-stormcrows-renamed-to-second-sons-in-game-of-thrones-tv-show

Comment: 5) I was sure that the slavers capitulated and gave all of their survived ships to Dany

Comment: 7) I thought that MArtells and Tyrells did not send their armies - they sent only ships to help with transportation

Comment: @Schullz: That's very probable. Also Reach may have sent some provisions as well. About 5, I thought so too, but did not find any evidence to prove it.

Comment: @Krumia :The Second Sons are staying behind in Meereen to keep the peace, as seen in the scene where Daario gets dumped.

Comment: The fleet brought by Yara and Theon is 100 ships, and they have crews to man them. It's explicitly mentioned in the Yara/Dany/Theon/Tyrion scene.

Comment: @Krumia I've rewatched the 9th episode. At first, they discussed the surrender of the Slavers. Later, Tyrion said "Thank you for your armada. Our queen does love ships". That can be a proof that Dany got the ships

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60433/what-companies-does-dany-command-in-meereen

Comment: We don't know exactly where this scene took place - instead of sending Tyrell/Martell ships to Mereen, this might be after the two fleets join on route in, say, Dorne or Volantis

Comment: @Schullz We do not about nature of the Tyrell Martell fleets. We don't even know where was that scene filmed. It could have been near the coast of Dorne which would be ideal for Tyrell and Martells to join up with Daenerys on her way to Kingslanding. It is not clear whether the fleets had armies or just crew.

Comment: She has 8,000 Unsullied as well as the Unsullied that are still in training. It's unclear how many are still in training.

Comment: We do not know exactly where was the scene of Dany's sailing shot. For all we know, she could have been on coast of Dorne where Dornish and Tyrell fleets could easily join them. Also we don't know what exactly was on those ships. Delegates? Soldiers? Supplies? In anycase, you should not assume that The fleets were in Meereen unless explicitly told so.

Comment: [Here you go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_the_human_body)

Answer (score 7):

Very good question, I'll try to answer point by point using references both from the book and from the show.

1. **Unsullied:** We do not know how many of them survived, but [8000 is the number of unsullied with complete training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GF7tFwLBiKo). Daenerys also bought the ones still under training, including uncut children. Some might have tried to return their homes after Daenerys released them, but not all. Hence, she might have even more than 8000 unsullied.
2. **Dothraki screamers:** We know that Khal Drogo had [40000 Dothraki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jcy37C5SN0M) in his horde. Dothraki has a government system very close to Turco-Mongol horde governments. When a strong leader emerges, leaders of other hordes either join him or fight and usually die so that their hordes are absorbed as well. This is why Khal Drogo had one of the largest hordes ever. However, Daenerys killed all other Khals in Vaes Dothrak. As a result, her horde cannot be smaller than Khal Drogos, while it can be larger.
3. **Iron Fleet:** Yara and Theon has escaped with [100 ships](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgH1teclWkY), while at that time the total Ironfleet was about 500 ships. Euron should now be commanding 1000 ships.
4. **Slaver's Navy:** We have no idea the size of their fleet. However, after Galiferyan's suggestion, we guess that [Daenerys arrived Westeros with 1000 ships](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRR0NlesJy8). We know that 100 of them are from Iron Fleet, while around 500 should be provided by Arbor (see below). We only know that Dorne has some navy, but not nearly as strong as that of Arbor's. Therefore, we can conjecture that Slaver's Navy may be around 200-300 ships.
5. **Sellswords:** To the best of my knowledge, Daenerys has transported no sellsword company to Westeros.
6. **Martells and Tyrells:** There are no Martells in the show, but we know from books that Dorne had 50000 spears untouched by the war of five kings. Who rules Dorne right now is unknown. Since Dorne is far away from King's Landing, Cersei may or may not have a control over Dorne. Renly had 100000 men, [both from Stormlands and the Reach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOzsRcjNZmQ). Although the exact strength of Reach is unknown, we know that it is the most populous kingdom in the seven kingdoms. I estimate the strength of the Reach around 70000-80000. The Reach has an immense navy as well. From books we know that Arbor, a vassal sworn to the Reach should be able to field a fleet closer to Iron Fleet in numbers. My estimate is that Reach Navy is composed of at least 200-300 ships maybe upto 500-600. Reach was probably ruled by Tarllys before they were burnt. Right now, we have no idea who rules them, however, unlike Dorne, it is probably someone that Cersei trusts.

Comment: I will try to add book references as soon as I have time. If you find the exact chapter, I can add them as well.

Comment: Daario tells Dany she needs at least a  thousand ships to sail all her armies, so we should estimate she had something around 1k ships before Deus Ex Euron.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Good point, I break it down like 100 Iron Fleet ships, 500 Arbor navy, 200 Dornish navy and 300 slavers' navy.

Answer (score -3):

I think that the Tyrells and Martels are all in for Dany at this point which gives Dany unlimited amounts resources and wealth given that House Tyrell is the richest House in Westeros at this point and seem to have strong ties to the Iron Bank. I don't think that the Tyrells/Martels would only 1/2 back Dany. If they did then they'd risk losing. At this point, they need to be all in to insure that the Lannister's are destroyed and that their plan pays off for them. Dany and her alliance have overwhelming numbers at this point. Everyone who opposes her are sitting ducks at this point.

Comment: Wasn't House Tyrell the 2nd richest house, after Lannister, as pointed put by Renley in some of the first episodes?

Comment: @Gallifreian On paper, yes - But I think I remember that at some point during the show, it was very clear that the Lannisters are running out of money. Of course, they don't admit that. Effectively, that would make Tyrell the richest ones.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka  -  makes sense, given their continuing war with a lot of people. Still, we'd have to know exactly how wealthy Lannisters and Tyrells were to make the comparison.